# jquery mobile pass data between two htmls with single page template

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquerymobile /jquery/ js and developing webpages. I want to pass data from one page to another.

With multipage template in jquerymobile Im able to achieve that but help me with single page template. Please please I dont want to use global variables or cookies or localstorage or using url. Trying to pass using Jquery.data but unable to achieve this. Please please post an example.

I have two pages. In second page connecting on "pagebeforeshow" event I'm not getting the b1 button object instead getting null.

```
$('#page2').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, data)
{
     console.log (data.prevPage.attr('#b1'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly using selector as an attribute name. That's why your code fails.
To get an element relative to `prevPage` you can use `find()` method. And then you can read attribute value by `attr()`.

Therefore to get your button change

```
console.log (data.prevPage.attr('#b1'));
```

to

```
console.log (data.prevPage.find('#b1').attr('id'));
                                              ^ or any other attribute that you need
```